# Suggest alternatives to wget

Tags: curl, wget, python-requests-html

The website I am trying to scrape blocks wget, resulting in a 502 error. However, Requests and cURL work fine for scraping one page at a time. Is there an alternative software or tool that allows me to scrape multiple pages like the --mirror and --convert-links options in Wget? Thanks you in advance.

Comment: Requests  **Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more** are off-topic here. Please delete and repost to [su] . Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Often used way to decide which downloader to allow is [`User-Agent` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent). You might use `--user-agent=agent-string` to make `wget` mimick browser, for example

```
wget --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0" http://www.example.com
```

also, as you want to download multiple pages I suggest setting wait as some servers detects many requests in short time, you need to find yourself value which should be not too low (avoid detection) and too high (long time to complete) for example if you decide 3 seconds is right value then you might use `--wait=3`

Answer (score 0):

install [windows terminal](https://apps.microsoft.com/detail/9N0DX20HK701?hl=en-us&gl=US) as its a really fast terminal.

then install [winget package manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/package-manager/winget/) to install packages quickly. you can use its search command to find packages using commands like `winget search wget`.

you will see this output:

```
Name  Id                  Version Match     Source
--------------------------------------------------
Wget  JernejSimoncic.Wget 1.21.4            winget
Wget2 GNU.Wget2           2.0.1   Tag: wget winget
```

now, you can install [wget2](https://gitlab.com/gnuwget/wget2) by using its `Id` with the following command:

```bash
winget install GNU.Wget2
```

i installed `wget2` because it claims to be better than `wget` otherwise you can install `wget` as well with `winget install JernejSimoncic.Wget`.

now you can easily use `wget2` in the windows terminal.

just replace `wget` in your scripts with `wget2` & it will work like a charm.